# How to set element to height 0px?

Tags: css, reactjs, height, border-box

I want to make my element dynamically change its height from initial to 0px but it seems to be not working because of padding. I cannot say what I am doing wrong.

I do not want use: display: block or visibility hidden. I do not want to remove padding from styles when height is 0 because it makes this logic too complicated. I hope that I am doing sth stupid and easy to fix here and it is why it is not working. Any ideas?

[image]

I am adding it for more context. It is React. I've simplified code - but it is basic idea. And I want to make this modal resizable. So I have :

```
const StyledModal = styled.div<ModalProps>`
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9000;
  background-color: white;
  height: ${({ height }) => `${height}px`};
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3.4rem 0 3.2rem 0;
`
const Modal = ({children}) => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => { 
    setHeight(ref && 
    ref.current && 
    ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().height)
  }, [])

  const reduceHeight = () => setHeight(0) 
  return <StyledModal 
          onClick={reduceHeight} 
          height={height}>{children}</StyledModal>

}
```

Problem is that even if I manually set height to 0px in web developer tools , this element exists because of this padding like in the screenshot above.

Comment: Its hard to determine from your question how the height is changed. If you're looking to change the height but include padding with JS, either innerHeight() or outerHeight() depending on your requirements will help

Comment: @beatnik I've added more context.